# No warning of uninitialiazed variables when -fcheck=all is used

Tags: gfortran

This is a Fortran code:

```
program sample
  implicit none
  real(8) :: notinit

  notinit= notinit*8
  write(*,*) 'notinit =',notinit
end program sample
```

With `gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)`

Two cases:

```
gfortran -O1 -ffree-line-length-0  -Wall -Wno-maybe-uninitialized sample.f90
sample.f90:5:0:

   notinit= notinit*8
 
Warning: ‘notinit’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

But

```
gfortran -O1 -ffree-line-length-0  -fcheck=all -Wall -Wno-maybe-uninitialized sample.f90
```

has no warning message, which is very wrong.

Why?

Comment: You might be spelling the option wrong.  gfortran can (now) determined that the variable is not initialized.  There is "no maybe' about it.  Try -Winitialized.

Comment: You may be right. But the last time I check -Wmaybe-uninitialized is valid. When this is set through -Wall. Any variable (especially arrays) that gfortran can't be sure will appear on the screen thus swarm those genuine warning messages. One way to turn it off is to use -Wno-** option to counter it. I suggest you compile the code above to confirm that this is not a typo problem.